# Getting a subnav bar to become a dropdown in smaller screensize

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Okay so first time here. Forgive me if I sound lost or silly. I hope you will help correct me if I made any mistakes. Anyways, I am trying to imitate the navbar on this website: [WOHA](https://woha.net//). I am not super concerned about getting it 100%. I have been able to somewhat imitate the on hover secondary navbar by using a jQuery onclick function toggle to make the secondary navbar appear when clicked, so it's close enough and satisfactory for me. What I am lost about is how to make it so that when the screen size gets smaller(as you can see from the linked website example I am trying to make a copy of), that the secondary navbar is accessible as a dropdown option via the main navbar. Would someone be kind enough to fill me in on what to do to achieve such a result?

```js
$( ".subnav-trigger-about" ).click(function() {
  $( "#subnav-about" ).toggle();
});
    
$( ".subnav-trigger-services" ).click(function() {
  $( "#subnav-services" ).toggle();
});
```

```css
#subnav-about {
  

  display: none;
}

#subnav-services {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #FFD700;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #FFD700;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  color: #FFD700;
}

@media (min-width: 988px) {
  #subnav-about {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    
  }

  #subnav-services {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
  

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">TEST</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 test">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="subnav-trigger-about nav-link">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link subnav-trigger-services">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">PROJECTS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- About Us Secondary Nav -->

  <nav id="subnav-about" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">TEST</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">EXPERTISE</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">PEOPLE</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Services Secondary Nav -->

  <nav id="subnav-services" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONSULTATION</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">MANAGEMENT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">TRAINING COURSES</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I feel like I need to do @media and interact with it somehow but I am also unsure of how to proceed

Edit: I have added a bit of content to my navbar since then but nothing that should have changed anything by much. A bit confused on why the code snippet by the guy below me works but mine doesn't. Would appreciate the help in figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you:

```js
$(".subnav-trigger").click(function() {
  $("#subnav").toggle();
});
```

```css
#subnav {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
#subnav{position: absolute; right:0; left:0;}}
```

```html
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">TEST</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="subnav-trigger nav-link">ABOUT</a>
 <nav id="subnav" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">TEST</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Expertise</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">People</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">SERVICES</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- About Us Secondary Nav -->
```

Comment: It isn't. I am not quite sure why. Like it shows up behind the main navbar. I can see it behind it. but it's not popping out like in your solution

Comment: @Digital_Explorer I am a little confused. Where exactly is it showing up behind the main navbar? is it in my code?

Comment: No. I figured it out. It was my fault. I forgot to nest the sub nav inside the  main nav

Comment: Glad you find it :)